# How to improve automatic activation time in IIS hosted WCF service

Tags: wcf, iis, iis-7

I have an IIS hosted WCF service and it will take long time to serve a request at first time. Subsequent requests served very fast. I believe this is due to automatic activation in IIS. Is there any way to keep WCF service is always running? Or improve automatic activation time?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Auto-Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677260%28v=azure.10%29.aspx).

One of many references Google gave me: 
[How to use AppFabric Auto-Start feature to avoid warm-up delays for IIS-hosted WCF Receive Locations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paolos/archive/2010/10/30/how-using-appfabric-auto-start-feature-to-avoid-warm-up-delays-for-iis-hosted-wcf-receive-locations.aspx)